# How to handle scheduled task in dropwizard in multiserver environment

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, apache-zookeeper, dropwizard, cron-task

I am working with `Dropwizard` and used `quartz jobs` to schedule tasks which runs every 20 hrs. The problem that I am facing is my code is deployed on 4 servers and the scheduled task is executed 4 times. I am trying to find out an optimal solution to handle the scenario, so that the task gets executed only once. I came across `Zookeeper` for managing multiple servers but I'm not able to understand how to schedule task on Zookeeper from Dropwizard. Any help would be great.

Comment: You can do it with Quartz, it can use a JDBC JobStore to manager a multi-server environment. Take a look at : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Comment: Hi @Dorian, I tried to use quartz schedular as you pointed, with all the quartz tables created in my database. The problem that I am facing is: Every time I restart my application, duplicate entries of jobs are created in quartz table. Do you have any idea how to handle this.

Comment: Add a cron url and call it from external. the call will be load balance to only one server.